# Linux/awk convert file containing decimal to hex

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I have a text file containing lots of RGB colour codes in decimal. For example

```
000,000,000
000,003,025
000,007,048
000,010,069
000,014,089
000,017,108
000,020,125
000,024,140
000,027,155
```

I would like to convert each line to hex format (desired output):

```
00,00,00
00,03,15
00,07,30
00,08,45
```

I know I can use `printf "%.2x,%.2x,%.2x\n" 000 010 69` however `printf "%.2x,%.2x,%.2x\n" 000 010 069` does not work as 069 is not convertable.

I thought `awk` would be a reasonable tool for the job, but I guess I would face the same problems converting decimals such as 069 etc.

`perl -le '$hex = sprintf("%.2x,%.2x,%.2x",005,69,255); print $hex'` also has the same issue with 069

Comment: Note that "printf "%x\n" 010" is even more dangerous than "printf "%x\n" 069" because it silently gives a result you are not expecting rather than exiting with an error. You can use "%02x" to pad hexadecimal numbers. Not sure about the best way to interpret numbers that would be octal in the C-style as decimal.

Comment: May be of some help: `bc <<< "obase=16; 069"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're simply missing the commas between the arguments:

```
echo "000,010,069" | awk -F ',' '{ printf "%02X,%02X,%02X\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
```

produces:

```
00,0A,45
```

Verified both on Mac OS X (BSD awk) and Linux (GNU awk).

Answer (score 8):

It works fine in awk:

```
$ echo 000,062,102 | awk '{printf( "%x,%x,%x\n", $1,$2,$3)}' FS=,
0,3e,66
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/([0-9]+)/sprintf "%02x", $1/ge' INPUT
```

You do not have to care about octal interpretation. It applies to literals only, not to values of variables.